# How can I save the id of the new wishlist in the field `wishlist_id` of `wishlist_entry`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to save the id of the `wishlist` in a `wishlist_entry` table in a column like `wishlist_id`.
I have an link_to element like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Create', new_wishlist_entry_path(:wishlist => @wishlist.id) %>
```

This gives me the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/wishlist_entries/new?wishlist=36
```

The wishlist_entry_controller's `new` action is:

```
def new
  @wishlist_entry = WishlistEntry.new
  @wishlist = Wishlist.find(params[:wishlist])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @wishlist_entry }
  end
end
```

The create action is:

```
def create
@wishlist_entry = WishlistEntry.new(
  :wishlist_id => Wishlist.find(params[:id]),
  :entry_name => params[:wishlist_entry][:entry_name],
  :description => params[wishlist_entry][:description]
)
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Wishlist without an ID
app/controllers/wishlist_entries_controller.rb:44:in `create'
```

The error is in the link:

```
:wishlist_id => Wishlist.find(params[:id]),
```

Whats wrong? How can I save the id of the new wishlist in the field `wishlist_id` of `wishlist_entry`?

Comment: my routes.rb looks so
  `get "welcome/index"`

  resources :wishlists
  
  resources :wishlist_entries
  
  resources :registrations
  
  resources :wishlists do
    resources :wishlist_entries
  end
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end`

Comment: The error screen should dump the params being sent to the create action. What are they?

Comment: The parameters `wishlist_entry"=>{"wishlist_id"=>"",`
 `"entry_name"=>"vvcv",`
 `"description"=>"CXVX"},`
 `"commit"=>"Create Wishlist entry"}`
In `wishlist_entry"=>{"wishlist_id"=>"",` should the id of the wishlist be saved

Comment: good evening for this night i have to go

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the wishlist id is coming in params[:wishlist] not params[:id]. The error you are seeing in your controller is because params[:id] is nil and the Wishlist class doesn't know what to do with Wishlist.find(nil).

Try this:

```
def create
  @wishlist_entry = WishlistEntry.new(
    :wishlist_id => params[:wishlist]),
    :entry_name => params[:wishlist_entry][:entry_name],
    :description => params[wishlist_entry][:description]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do here, it looks like the problem is that wishlist_id isn't getting passed to your create action.

The best way to fix this is to take advantage of the nested resources you've already set up by changing

```
<%= link_to 'Create', new_wishlist_entry_path(:wishlist => @wishlist.id) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Create', new_wishlist_wishlist_entry_path(:wishlist => @wishlist.id) %>
```

(`wishlist_wishlist_entry` looks pretty bad, but you can change it by using `:as => 'whatever'` [in your routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names))

Then in your new action:

```
@wishlist = Wishlist.find(params[:wishlist_id])
```

In your form:

```
form_for([@wishlist, @wishlist_entry])
```

And in your create action:

```
@wishlist = Wishlist.find(params[:wishlist_id])
@wishlist_entry = @wishlist.wishlist_entries.build(params[:wishlist_entry])
```

Comment: This doesn't work the error is the same...
Now i try to explain what i want to do here
First i have the create action of the wishlist. The User can create it. After the creation her can add one or more wishes to his new list.
The workflow in my dreams is so. You came to the site create your wishlist. With name, e-mail and description and after that you can directly add your wish to the list. No Optin, no password

Comment: The first time it runs so. The new action of wishlist_entry
<br />

`@wishlist_entry = WishlistEntry.new`
`@wishlist_entry.wishlist_id = params[:wishlist]`

Comment: And the show.htm.erb has this link
`<%= link_to 'Create', new_wishlist_entry_path(:wishlist => @wishlist.id) %> |`